# How can I add Git tags in Bitbucket?

Tags: git, tags, bitbucket

I'm hosting my code on Bitbucket using Git. My local client is EGit (eclipse plugin). I created a tag locally (Team -> Advanced -> Tag) and then pushed it to remote repository. But when I open my repository page, I can't find tags there. I'm pretty sure the tag can be seen locally.

I'm not a Git expert. But it seems to me there are several types of tags in Git. Does Bitbucket only show certain types of tags?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Did you click the button "Add All Tags Spec" in Push Wizard in Eclipse? If not, try it.
Or if you have access to console version of git just perform:

```
git push --tags
```

Answer (score 58):

You can also add the tag directly in the Bitbucket UI. Look at `Commits`, choose a specific commit and then in the details on the right side of the page, click the `+`-button after `No tags`.

[image]

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/repository-tags-321860179.html

Comment: is this the same answer as Brian van Rooijen's (https://stackoverflow.com/a/39018405/3368818), but with a screenshot?

Answer (score 25):

[This documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging) indicates that a tag could be created. Based on that information the following command was constructed:

```
git tag --annotate 1.0.0 --message "Initial version of some app"
```

and pushed by issuing:

```
git push origin 1.0.0
```

Once pushed, the tag could be downloaded by navigating to `https://bitbucket.org/<username>/<project>/downloads?tab=tags`

Answer (score 22):

If you don't know where to look it will take ages to find the button in the gui.

In the bitbucket gui you can add a tag by browsing to commits. When you open the commit you want to tag there is a "tags" section in the top right of the page. Just below where the branch is displayed. If you click the + button you can tag your commit.

We are running the following version: 
Atlassian Bitbucket v4.8.3

Comment: This Bitbucket gui tag browse to commits solution also solves  the valid-key permissions command line git push --tags issue . Reference https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/37533680/-jira-hooks-for-stash-is-blocking-my-tags-push

Comment: Discovered the tag with the Bitbucket gui commit only created a temporary tag. As "admin", I had to go into hooks and temporarily disable the "Push Check" hook. Then the command line "git push --tags" worked.

Comment: @zerocog, With the latest version of Bitbucket this no longer is a temporary tag.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I had to do, but it seems awfully longwinded. Does anyone know a quicker approach?

rt click on tag under the git repository view.
Push Tags, 
choose remote repo, 
choose target ref name (ctrl-space) to be refs/heads/master. 
Select finish.
On the results screen, Select configure
select advanced, 
select add all tags spec, 
select "finish". 
This creates a ref mappings in the configure push page with refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*.
Now hit save and push.

Answer (score 1):

In the `commits`, select the `Details` tab on the right-hand side of the page, scroll down and you can find the `tags`. Create one if needed.

This is the same answer as @Ogglas [has provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56539046/7562022). But I'd like to upload a new screenshot since the GUI is changed.

[image]